# Device reenabling ability to wake PC from sleep on its own

Tags: windows, mouse, sleep, hibernate, wake-up

I have problem.
Some of my devices like wireless mouse and keyboard re enable option: "Allow this device to wake the computer" in Device Manager.

1. I run command: `powercfg -devicequery wake_armed`
   to see devices that can wake my PC. I see "Mouse" here.
2. I disable mouse's ability to wake the PC and run this command to check.
3. Device disappears from this list.
4. I put my PC to Sleep/Hibernation (doesn't matter)
5. I move my mouse and PC wakes up.
6. I run this command again just after PC wakes up. `powercfg -devicequery wake_armed` and see that mouse is again able to wake my PC. It is also enabled by it

How can I prevent Mouse and other devices to enable option to wake the PC by itself?